# Fortran + OpenMP + polymorphism: what exactly is not supported?

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, openmp

I am aware that the OpenMP 4.5 standard says that in Fortran "polymorphic entities" are not supported.

What exactly does this mean? Does this only exclude calls to type-bound procedures that have a PASS attribute, but I can still use an instance of a user-defined type that has type-bound procedures in other ways (e.g. accessing its components)?

Does this limitation only apply to the OMP PARALLEL block, or also to procedures called from this block, or to the entire compilation unit?

Would be great if someone could point me to some clarifying documentation.
Thanks!

EDIT: Made explicit that I meant type-bound procedures with the PASS attribute specified.

Comment: I can't say exactly what it means, but note that polymorphism and having type-bound procedures are very different concepts.

Comment: Who knows. They also didn't support `associate` before although there was nothing obviously problematic in my non-language-lawyer eyes in there.

Comment: I definitely call type bound procedures in a lot of my OpenMP code.

Comment: @francescalus: OK, I should have been more specific in that I mean type-bound procedures with the PASS attribute specified, which are necessary for polymorphic usage. Without polymorphic procedure calls there is not much of a point of having type-bound procedures anyways, unless you strongly prefer foo%bar() over bar(foo).