# Fortran polymorphic variables and OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am learning about Fortran polymorphic variables. When I try to compile my program with OpenMP I get:

```
internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
```

I am using GNU gfortran 7.3.0 and OpenMP 4.5.
Here is my test program (runs normally without `-fopenmp` compiler flag):

```
program main
  !$ use omp_lib
  implicit none
  class(*), allocatable :: obj
  integer               :: tid = 0, stat

  !$OMP PARALLEL PRIVATE(tid, stat, obj)
  !$ tid = OMP_get_thread_num()

  allocate( integer :: obj, STAT=stat )
  if ( stat /= 0 ) stop "Allocation error."

  select type( obj )
  type is ( integer )
    obj = tid
    write (*,*) obj

  end select

  !$OMP END PARALLEL

end program main
```

From what I could gather Fortran polymorphic are not supported in OpenMP 4.5? Or are at least partially supported? See [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188844/fortran-openmp-polymorphism-what-exactly-is-not-supported).

Is this feature supported in OpenMP 5.0 and newer gfortran compiler?
All I could find is:

> - Support for the latest versions of C, C++, and Fortran. OpenMP now supports important features of Fortran 2008, C11, and C++17. [Cite](https://www.openmp.org/press-release/openmp-5-0-is-a-major-leap-forward/)

Comment: It appears to be supported by OMP 5.0. For firstprivate, lastprivate and copyprivate the behavior is unspecified.

Comment: Q: Why does firstprivate result in unspecified behavior? I would expect that the same type would be allocated/created when entering parallel region?

Comment: It results in unspecified behaviour because that is what the standard says (see section 12.9.4.4 at https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu106.html#x139-5680002.19.4.4). It's rarely worth worrying beyond that.

Comment: If you ever get an internal compiler error you should report it to the compiler supplier (in this case https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/ seems to be the right place for that). There is no point asking about the semantics of your code; compilers should never crash, even if fed binary output or your shopping list!